# Python Concatenate two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries,

```
var1 = {'name': 'alice'}
var2 = {'name': 'bob'}
```

I would like to concatenate these to produce,

```
var3 = {'name': 'alice'},{'name': 'bob'}
```

How is this achieved?

Comment: var1 and var2 are set, not a dictionary

Comment: no.. that are not dictionaries.

Comment: Do you mean `{'alice', 'bob'}` for var3?

Comment: and `var3` is currently a tuple. If you wanted to do that, well, `var3 = var1, var2` would work.

Comment: You don't have the correct data type defined in your example. Also, you should make the dictionaries that you do correctly define more complex as your single value dictionaries are hiding multiple value complexities that your code will need to deal with. Dictionaries have `key,value` pairs, e.g. `dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'};`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: My mistake: The types of var1 and var2 are dictionaries, and the type of var3 is a tuple.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to NightShadeQueen for the correct solution:

To obtain `var3`, doing `var3 = var1,var2` is the way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

To add the key-value pairs of `dict2` to the ones of `dict1` you can use `dict1.update(dict2)`. This modifies `dict1` obviously though.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Better is `dict3 = dict(dict1); dict3.update(dict2)`.  Otherwise you mutate one of the original dicts.  However this is all a moot point.  OP really wanted a tuple of dictionaries, not a single dict.